# Obtaining inserted sqlite from command line

Tags: sqlite, bash

I use bash to access a sqlite3 database.

Is there a way to get the last inserted id that way, because on the sqlite-webpage (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) I only see the C-API, but no way to do it on the command line.

The function last_insert_rowid() does not work either:

```
sqlite> last_insert_rowid();
SQL error: near "last_insert_rowid": syntax error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

should be

```
select last_insert_rowid();
```